# How to checkout two working copy from two different branches each time I push to one of those branches?

Tags: git, bash

I have two branches for an application, those two branches use two different config file for our application. in the remote server I was using

```
GIT_WORK_TREE="/home/webui/projects/startmeup-ui" git checkout -f
```

that worked perfectly, then I modified it so that depending of what branch I'm pushing to it will checkout a copy to a different directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    echo "this is branch '$branch'" > /home/webui/mytest.txt
    if [ "master" = "$branch" ]; then
        echo "if was true, means 'master'" >> /home/webui/mytest.txt
        GIT_WORK_TREE="/home/webui/projects/startmeup-ui" git checkout -f
    else
        echo "if was false, means 'debugging'" >> /home/webui/mytest.txt
        GIT_WORK_TREE="/home/webui/projects/navops-test" git checkout -f
    fi
done
```

as you can see I'm writing to a file `/home/webui/mytest.txt` in order to see what's going on. the output in this file is as expected

```
this is branch 'debugging'
if was false, means 'debugging'
```

when I push to debbugging and

```
this is branch 'master'
if was true, means 'master'
```

when I push to master

the problem is that the content in /home/webui/projects/navops-test doesn't get updated when I push to debugging

any idea why?

Comment: What does `git checkout -f` output in the debugging case?

Comment: I updated the script to 
`GIT_WORK_TREE="/home/webui/projects/navops-test" git checkout -f &>> /home/webui/mytest.txt`

and there is not any output from git checkout -f :-(

Comment: You might want to read [checkout -- the "fight club" of git deployment](http://gitolite.com/deploy.html#checkout----the-fight-club-of-git-deployment) (and the rest of the page) for doing what you are trying to do here. The lack of a target ref in the checkout is probably the issue. I'm betting you find out that `git checkout -f` says "Nothing to do" or "no such ref master" or something like that.

Comment: thanks!!! for the article the solution was very simple,
`git checkout -f $branch`